# Value of $i^\sqrt3$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponentiation

> Find all values of $i^\sqrt3$.

I am trying to apply de Moivre's formula here but cannot find a way to do so. I am not sure if i am approaching this wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: by definition, $b^c = \exp(c \log b)$.  Use all values of $\log b$.

Comment: thanks, and b here does not need to a real number? (need a little explanation if possible)

Comment: But then: $i^\sqrt{3}=\exp(\sqrt{3}\ln{i})=\exp(\sqrt{3}i(\pi/2+2\pi n)) [\forall n \in Z]$, which has infinit results?

Comment: *Infinitely many* results, @Roger. Yes. In fact, raising a nonpositive complex number to an exponent that’s not an integer will always be ill-defined, with perhaps infinitely many values.

Answer (score 1):

Consider: from deMoivre's

$e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta \tag 1$

with

$\theta = 2n \pi + \dfrac{\pi}{2}, \; n \in \Bbb Z, \tag 2$

we have

$e^{i(2n\pi + \pi/2)} = i; \tag 3$

thus

$i^{\sqrt 3} = e^{i(2n\pi + \pi/2)\sqrt 3}$
$= \cos ((2n\pi + \pi/2)\sqrt 3) + i \sin ((2n\pi + \pi/2)\sqrt 3), \ n \in \Bbb Z. \tag 4$

We may check for consistency: (4) yields

$-i = i^3 = (i^{\sqrt 3})^{\sqrt 3} $
$= (e^{i(2n\pi + \pi/2)\sqrt 3})^{\sqrt 3} = e^{i(2n\pi + \pi/2)(3)}$
$= e^{6\pi i}e^{3\pi i /2} = -i. ✓ \tag 5$

Comment: Great! I appreciate often your answer....my sincere and cordial greetings.

Comment: @Sebastiano:  greetings to you as well, my friend . . . and thanks for the kind words!

Answer (score 0):

The [de Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) is useful when you deal with a complex number of the form $e^{ix}$ ($x\in\mathbb{R}$).

When you have exponentiation of a complex number, what you should look for first is the *[definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Complex_exponents_with_complex_bases)*, particularly when you have $z^w$ where $z$ is a complex number and $w$ is not an integer.

In your case,
$$
i^{\sqrt{3}}:=\exp(\sqrt{3}\log(i))
$$
where $\log$ denotes the [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm), which is a multi-valued function.